# blender 2.90.1 : I can't make work the knife tool and mirror together

Tags: mirror

[image: issue with mirring knife exemple]

As you can see on the picture, I tried to cut a face with the knife tool while having the mirror modifier.

It seems to work well until you realize that on the mirrored cut, no vertices have been created, it is just showing a fake edge that cannot be selected.
on the left part, I can select the two faces that result from the cut, while on the right part, I can only select the origin face.

Do you have an idea on what I am doing badly?

I have seen in another thread that the object has to be symetrical. Mine should be as I created a cylinder with 12 sides, and just extruded the top vertices before making the cut.

Thanks in advance for helping me (trying to learn blender is a really cumbursome journey ! )

Comment: You need to apply the modifier in order to be able to select the mirrored geometry. But in your case it will result in double vertices on the other side. I suggest enabling "Bisect" along the X axis in the modifier to see what I mean

Comment: Wow, ok !
Thanks a lot for your answer, it helped quite a lot.

For the next that will have the issue, I went crazy as I thought that it was not working. I was working on the right part of the symetry and the doc says that when using bisect, the negative side is kept for applying the symetry, so in my case, I had to work on theleft part to make it work

Comment: You can also enable "Flip" to reverse that :)